# Editing an Order on Magento's admin panel

Tags: edit

Sometimes we have customers that order the incorrect products.  I need to be able to edit their order to reflect the correct product so that when they view their order history the correct product shows and not the incorrect product.  However, when I go to the order in question and choose edit, I get the "are you sure? this will cancel this order and start a new one" message.  I choose ok and it creates a new order, however it doesn't do anything to the original order.  It leaves it open and pending/processing.  Should it work this way, or should it actually cancel the original order?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248938/magento-ce-1-7-0-2-editing-order-not-canceling-original

Take a look here. If your payment method for example automatically sets the status of an order to processing etc the the order can only be refunded/closed not cancelled, so you will have to either:

- manually refund/close the old order OR
- check your payment method which is where you tend to set what state the order will be in when complete and change to pending